# Using an ISA relationship in mysql

Tags: mysql

i currently have 3 entities. Employees, teachers, and custodians. All teachers and custodians are employees. All employees have an id, name, and email. I have tried connected custodians and teachers to Employees using an ISA relationship with primary and foreign keys. I am attempting to create the tables, so that when i create a "teacher"  or a "custodian" the Employee table is also populated. I currently have only an id for teacher/custodian linked to the employee. am i doing this wrong? thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE employees(
id INT UNSIGNED,
first_name VARCHAR(30),
last_name VARCHAR(30),
email VARCHAR(60),
Primary Key (id));

CREATE TABLE teacher(
teach_id INT UNSIGNED,
)

CREATE TABLE teachemp(
id INT UNSIGNED,
teach_id INT UNSIGNED,
PRIMARY KEY(id,teach_id),
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES employees(id),
FOREIGN KEY (teach_id) REFERENCES teacher(teach_id)
)
```

In other words, when i create insert an employee and that employee is a teacher. i want the teacher table to also be populated. am i doing this correctly? or should i create a teacher and the employee table be populated?

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean populated? if data inserted from first table then insert also to second table? explain your needs clearly..Your example is just creating table no more else..

Comment: so i want to insert a teacher and also see that entry in the employee table.

Comment: Use trigger...... that's all

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need...

Follow this [Trigger](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/41414/sql-server-coding-the-after-insert-trigger-in-sql-server/) Example for SQL.

and this [Trigger](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php) for MYSQL

Comment: Every developer just need to read to discover something not just waiting for an answer...

Comment: well what i am asking is whether the way i set up my tables is correct or not.,... @reds